# Build link with parameter (?key=val) with ui-sref directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular ui-router, my state look like:

```
.state('detail', {
    url: '/detail/{id}',
```

In the HTML file I prefer to use ui-serf directive to build the link. For example:

```
<a ui-sref="detail( { id:123 } )">...
```

How can I build a link with optional query parameter? For example:

```
/detail/123?mode=json&pretty=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the `ui-router` way it's not to use query parameters, but instead of doing:

```
/detail/123?mode=json&pretty=true
```

declare the state as

```
.state('detail', {
    url: '/detail/{id}/{format}/{pretty}',
    ...
```

and using it like:

```
/detail/123/json/true
```

Anyway, if you really want to use the query format, you can do it out-of-the-box like as state in the doc:

> You can also specify parameters as query parameters, following a '?':
>
> url: "/contacts?myParam" // will match to url of
>   "/contacts?myParam=value" If you need to have more than one, separate
>   them with an '&':
>
> url: "/contacts?myParam1&myParam2" // will match to url of
>   "/contacts?myParam1=value1&myParam2=wowcool"

See: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just adding it? :

```
 <a ui-sref="detail( { id:123, optional: 'moo' } )">...
```

I know that is how dotJEM angular routing would work ( except the syntax is a bit different ).